# Is there a way to export mulitple layer combinations as JPEG or PNG files in Inkscape?

Tags: export, layer, inkscape

I have a SVG with multiple layers, I wonder it there is an automatic way to show/hide certain layers and export these combinations as PNG or JPG files. I came across this extension
[https://inkscape.org/~Xaviju/%E2%98%85inkscape-export-layers-extension](https://inkscape.org/%7EXaviju/%E2%98%85inkscape-export-layers-extension)

which apparently does what I want, but I saved it in the user extensions inkscape folder and it doesn't show up in the Extensions--> Export menu after I restart Inkscape. Maybe because of the version I'm using (1.0.2).

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one will help?

https://gitlab.com/Moini/inx-exportobjects

It allows you to keep one or more layers constant, and to export to various formats.

Just noticed that you shouldn't check 'export visible layers only', it errors out (until I've fixed it, that is).